# device validation layer vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

Hello, I'm beginning with vulkan API, I'm trying to show Validation layers.
But the problem is I only have access to one device validation layer : "VK_LAYER_NV_optimus"

```
{//Enumerating Device Verification Layers
    uint32_t layer_count = 0;
    vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(_gpu, &layer_count, nullptr);
    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> layer_property_list(layer_count);
    vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(_gpu, &layer_count, layer_property_list.data());
    std::cout << "Device Layers : \n";
    for (auto &i : layer_property_list) {
        std::cout << "  " << i.layerName << "\t\t | " << i.description << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In the tutorial i'm following the guys have way more layers whose "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation" he is using.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toRPu.png) you can see what the guy got.

I though maybe the tutorial isn't up to date but i can't find anything related to this topic.

thanks for helping :)

Comment: Try enabling layers through environment variables. This way You don't have to recompile Your code to enable or disable specific layers. But apart from that - recently I installed the latest version of Vulkan SDK (on Windows) and layers didn't work. I had to add missing entries to the registry.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`.

Device layers were deprecated in Vulkan some time ago, essentially making all layers instance layers.  In this case, the Optimus layer is probably being registered as both an instance and a device layer, which is allowed and is why it shows up when you list the device layers.

If that does not help, you may have an installation problem that is preventing you from seeing the layers.  Consider running `vulkaninfo` or `via` to help troubleshoot the problem.

Finally, not all layers are validation layers.  When you enumerate the layers, you'll find layers that perform other functions, as seen in the screenshot you provided.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that on updated drivers `vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties` returns exactly the same list of layers that are enabled on `vkCreateInstance`. Optimus is implicit layer so it would be enabled and so show in `vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties`.

Comment: I used `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` then I got several results and VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation is in, thanks.

so i guess the tutorial isn't up to date

Comment: my bad the tutorial says that device layers are deprecated